# Java using hashmap for searching string

Tags: java, string, hashmap, compare, hashtable

Is it possible to compare characters from a **string** and print out the position of the first unique one? Is there maybe something from the String class that can help me do this?

Pseudocode:

```
enter code here
String s = "ABC456";
int n = 2;


ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Long> counts2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, 
Long>();
for(String val : str){
    long count = counts2.getOrDefault(val, 0L);
    counts2.put(val, ++count);
}
for(String key: counts2.keySet()){
    if(counts2.get(key)==1){
        System.out.println(list.indexOf(key));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is to be output when the second unique set is encountered....1? In your example, each substring set is unique so the output would be: `0,1,2,3,4` Or are you talking about unique to the Array of substrings?

Comment: Yes I think I was very unclear. Unique to the Array of substrings @DevilsHnd

Comment: Hi&Welcome to [so]! Please show what you tried with a hashmap.. Maybe some "regex magician" can `replace` that, but I think a (O(n)) loop + a hashmap (with n-character-keys, and index as value) is the way to go

Comment: @xerx593 there u go

Comment: @user16320675 and...

Comment: Its not duplicate? Read and compare

Comment: @user16320675 ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try mine:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String originalString = "AAAB"; //little trickier input! ;)
    int n = 1;

    LinkedHashSet<String> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> dupes = new HashSet<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> str2Idx = new HashMap<>();

    for (int cur = 0; cur <= originalString.length() - n; cur++) {

      String substr = originalString.substring(cur, cur + n);

      if (uniques.contains(substr)) { // cleanup
        uniques.remove(substr);
        str2Idx.remove(substr);
        dupes.add(substr);
      } else if(!dupes.contains(substr)){ // store
        uniques.add(substr);
        str2Idx.put(substr, cur);
      }
    }
    // when the input is "external"/unknown, we should also avoid:
    if (uniques.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(-1);
    } else {
      // Print(get the index of (first element of uniques))
      System.out.println(str2Idx.get(uniques.iterator().next()));
      // Prints "3" with the given input
    }
  }
}
```

So basically:

- a `LinkedHashSet` for unique substrings.

  - "Linked": preserves order
  - and "Hash": makes `contains` operation faster
- a `HashMap<String, Integer`, as the (variable) name suggest:

  - With (unique) substrings as keys
  - and their index (of first occurrence) as value
- an additional "dupes" storage, to avoid re-adding.

Please test it deeper.

Comment: This looks very clean thank you sir will try it!

Comment: Sir it seems like it doesnt work if I change  the string to  "AAAB" and n = 1 I get the answer 2. But the answer should be 3. And when I tried another long string that was unique with n = 10 I got an answer but I was expecting an error @xerx593

Comment: yes, i understand the problem: it's swapping A forth and back... i overwork!;)

Comment: I would appreciate if you edit the solution :)

Comment: sorry, guys, i am little in a hurry (now), and this was the "least intrusive quickest fix": one additional "dupes" hashset, to avoid re-adding.. and i had to fix the loop little: `cur < originalString.length() - n + 1`

Comment: or just `cur <= originalString.length() - n` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247953/discussion-between-zedoryasuo-and-xerx593).